# Can I use regular matching to get results？

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have a string `'/blog/:year/:month/:day/:slug'` and I hope to match the following results.

```
 ["/blog/:year/", "/blog/:year/:month/", "/blog/:year/:month/:day/"]
```

Please

e.g.

```js
const str = '/blog/2020/05/12/first'
// output: ['/blog/2020', '/blog/2020/05', '/blog/2020/05/12']
// or ['/blog/2020/', '/blog/2020/05/', '/blog/2020/05/12/']
```

e.g.

```js
const reg = '/blog/:year/:month/:day/:slug'
const result = reg.split('/').reduce((a, b) => {
  a = Array.isArray(a) ? a : []
  a.push([a[a.length - 1], b].join('/'))
  return a
})
console.log(result.slice(1, -1))
// output: ['/blog/:year', '/blog/:year/:month', '/blog/:year/:month/:day']
```

Comment: Hello, please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of Stackoverflow.

Comment: What is your expected result? What is your actual result? And how do you achieve your actual result (post code)?

Answer (score 0):

```
/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/
```

That regex work with string like this

1. '/1blog641/2003/12/04/:slug' => 1blog641/2003/12/04
2. '/someWordWitoutSpaces123/2003/12/04/:slug' => someWordWitoutSpaces123/2003/12/04

You can train there https://regexr.com/
Or read cheatsheet  https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks for answer. but It's not fixed，e.g. '/blog/:year/:month/:slug'

Comment: @linka (\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})|(\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\/\d{4}\/\d{2})|(\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\/\d{4})  this catch all of you need

Comment: right example In the title, I think reg it looks grace.

Comment: @linka are you try (\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2})|(\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\/\d{4}\/\d{2})|(\/[A-Za-z0-9]+\/\d{4})  ? If you need 1 regex to all of 3 type, you can split my big at " | "